# Vue v-cloak directive does not work on component

Tags: vue.js

I added v-cloak directive on the top div in my component and added css as in docs, set a timeout but it does not work I can see else content and the form styles. 
Component code:

```
<div class="form-in-wrap" v-cloak>
        <ul id="example-1" v-if="reports.length>0">
            <report-component v-for="report in reports" :report="report" :key="report.id" :options="options">
            </report-component>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Component script:

```
<script>
import ReportComponent from "./ReportComponent";

export default {
    components: {ReportComponent},
    data: function () {
        return {
            reports: {
                type: Array,
            },
            report: {
                ...
            },
        }
    },
    created: function () {
        var self = this
        setTimeout(function () {
            self.loadData('/reports')
        }, 2000);

    },
    methods: {
        loadData: function() { 
             get method
        }
    }
</script>
<style scoped>
[v-cloak] {
    display: none !important;
}
</style>
```

All example creates a Vue instance, but I am using export default in my component. Also it is not a main component, it is included with router can this be the case why it does not work?

Comment: From the docs: This directive will remain on the element until the associated Vue instance finishes `compilation`. LoadData is your function and has nothing to do with compilation of the template.

Comment: Thank you, done this as described in https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-after-navigation